# multiple predict model tensorflow by input dataframe

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis

So i build a tensorflow sequence model,but when i try predict by a single list like `test =  [bla bla bla]` it work fine and give me a result of `netral` but when I insert dataframe and change it into multiple list I got the result only for netral and I try a few things,under this one of my code example

```
import numpy as np
y_label = {0:"negative",1:"neutral",2:"positive"}
data_predict = pd.read_excel("data clear.xlsx")
data_predict = data_predict.dropna()
data_predict.head()
data_predict.isna().sum()
new = data_predict.values.tolist() #change into multiple list
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(new)
padded = pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_length,padding=padding_type,truncating=trunc_type)
data_prediction = model.predict(padded)
for x in data_prediction:
    np.array(x)
    print(y_label[np.argmax(prediction)])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
neutral
neutral
neutral
neutral
neutral
......
```

When I see the `padded` it show

```
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

does anyone can give a clue how to input dataframe into .predict ?

Comment: Did you really create a new profile after asking this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878939/return-tensorflow-predict-by-string-not-an-array

Comment: I new at new SO and I will split my account from personal and professional project,I forgot to log out when I asked this question from my pro account

Comment: Hi thanks for helping,I already accept you answer.If you have a doc or clue about my question above I will be very helped.Thanks

Comment: What is the shape / size of `new = data_predict.values.tolist()`? What is inside this list? And shouldn't you be using `x`in your `np.argmax` instead of `prediction`?

Comment: the list contain text for sentiment analysis the shape before i change from dataframe to list is `(977, 1)` . Any idea how `.predict` can take multiple list?